# Is the following synthesizable?

Tags: verilog

Hi I am trying to create a verilog register that outputs its value only when the write signal is high else it is high impedance. Is the following synthesizable?

```
module R(data_from_bus,data_to_bus,clk,read,write);
    input [7:0]data_from_bus;
    input clk,read,write;
    output reg[7:0] data_to_bus;
    reg[7:0] r_reg;
    always@(posedge clk)
    begin
    if (read==1)
        r_reg<=data_from_bus;
    end
    always@(write)
    begin
        if (write==1)
             data_to_bus=r_reg;
        else
             data_to_bus=8'bz;
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is synthesizable, but not necessarily doing what you want because of the questionable format.

here's a better (safer) version:

```
module R(data_from_bus,data_to_bus,clk,read,write);
    input [7:0]data_from_bus;
    input clk,read,write;
    output data_to_bus;
    reg[7:0] r_reg;

    always@(posedge clk) begin
        if (read)
            r_reg<=data_from_bus;
        else
            r_reg<=r_reg;
    end

    wire[7:0] r_reg_wire;
    assign r_reg_wire = r_reg;
    assign data_to_bus = write ? r_reg_wire : 8'bz;

endmodule
```

the main problem of the one you posted is that you are not having an else statement for the first non-blocking assignment: (if (read == 1))
This might result in inferring a latch (but tools are most likely smart enough to fix it implicitly), which does the same thing in simulation as a flip-flop in simulation, but will mess with timing in real life deployment

a really good approach is to use 'always_ff' for registers assignment, 'always_comb' for combinational logic assignment, and 'always_latch' for intended latch (which is rarely used apart from really fishy timing case such as clock gating); but these keyword are only supported in SystemVerilog

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Here is the result of synthesizing the posted code in the free online tools available at the EDA Playground website, using Mentor Precision.

Please add r_reg to the sensitivity list for the combinational logic to assure the simulation and synthesis results agree.    Use always @(*) to accomplish the same thing using a wildcard style approach.

Synthesis ran and produced no errors.

The log is shown below.
The last part of the log is a post synthesis Verilog netlist.
Note the tool used the FDRE primitive to implement the registers bits.

To repeat this process, see the reference design at:
https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2BmJ

- Copy the reference design to your EDA Playground account (assuming you have one;you should its free and helpfu) using the copy button.
- Paste the design you want to synthesize into the design.v tab.
- Run it by clicking the run button.

Log file

```
[2022-05-08 23:57:07 UTC] precision -shell -file run.do -fileargs "design.sv" && sed 's-$-<br>-g' precision.v > tmp.html && echo '<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <style> body {font-family: monospace;} </style> </head> <body>' > tmp2.html && echo '</body> </html> ' > tmp3.html && cat tmp2.html tmp.html tmp3.html > precision.html 
precision: Setting MGC_HOME to /usr/share/precision/Mgc_home ...
precision: Executing on platform: Derived from Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.1 (Source)  -- 5.4.0-107-generic -- x86_64 
//  Precision RTL Synthesis 64-bit 2021.1.0.4 (Production Release) Tue Jul 20 01:22:31 PDT 2021
//  
//  Copyright (c) Mentor Graphics Corporation, 1996-2021, All Rights Reserved.
//             Portions copyright 1991-2008 Compuware Corporation
//                       UNPUBLISHED, LICENSED SOFTWARE.
//            CONFIDENTIAL AND PROPRIETARY INFORMATION WHICH IS THE
//          PROPERTY OF MENTOR GRAPHICS CORPORATION OR ITS LICENSORS
//  
//  Running on Linux runner@eaa22c631d4a #121-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 24 16:04:27 UTC 2022 5.4.0-107-generic x86_64
//  
//  Start time Sun May  8 19:57:09 2022
# -------------------------------------------------
# Info: [9569]: Logging session transcript to file /home/runner/precision.log
# Warning: [9508]: Results directory is not set. Use new_project, open_project, or set_results_dir.
# Info: [9577]: Input directory: /home/runner
# Info: [9572]: Moving session transcript to file /home/runner/precision.log
# Info: [9558]: Created project /home/runner/project_1.psp in folder /home/runner.
# Info: [9531]: Created directory: /home/runner/impl_1.
# Info: [9557]: Created implementation impl_1 in project /home/runner/project_1.psp.
# Info: [9578]: The Results Directory has been set to: /home/runner/impl_1/
# Info: [9569]: Logging project transcript to file /home/runner/impl_1/precision.log
# Info: [9569]: Logging suppressed messages transcript to file /home/runner/impl_1/precision.log.suppressed
# Info: [9552]: Activated implementation impl_1 in project /home/runner/project_1.psp.
# Info: [20026]: MultiProc: Precision will use a maximum of 8 logical processors.
# Info: [15302]: Setting up the design to use synthesis library "xca7.syn"
# Info: [585]: The global max fanout is currently set to 10000 for Xilinx - ARTIX-7.
# Info: [15328]: Setting Part to: "7A100TCSG324".
# Info: [15329]: Setting Process to: "1".
# Info: [7513]: The default input to Vivado place and route has been set to "Verilog".
# Info: [7512]: The place and route tool for current technology is Vivado.
# Info: [3052]: Decompressing file : /usr/share/precision/Mgc_home/pkgs/psr/techlibs/xca7.syn in /home/runner/impl_1/synlib.
# Info: [3022]: Reading file: /home/runner/impl_1/synlib/xca7.syn.
# Info: [645]: Loading library initialization file /usr/share/precision/Mgc_home/pkgs/psr/userware/xilinx_rename.tcl
# Info: [40000]: hdl-analyze, Release RTLC-Precision 2021a.12
# Info: [42003]: Starting analysis of files in library "work"
# Info: [41002]: Analyzing input file "/home/runner/design.sv" ...
# Info: [670]: Top module of the design is set to: R.
# Info: [668]: Current working directory: /home/runner/impl_1.
# Info: [40000]: RTLC-Driver, Release RTLC-Precision 2021a.12
# Info: [40000]: Last compiled on Jul  2 2021 08:23:33
# Info: [44512]: Initializing...
# Info: [44504]: Partitioning design ....
# Info: [40000]: RTLCompiler, Release RTLC-Precision 2021a.12
# Info: [40000]: Last compiled on Jul  2 2021 08:49:53
# Info: [44512]: Initializing...
# Info: [44522]: Root Module R: Pre-processing...
# Info: [44523]: Root Module R: Compiling...
# Warning: [45784]: "/home/runner/design.sv", line 11: Module R, Net(s) r_reg[7:0]: Although this signal is not part of the sensitivity list of this block, it is being read. This may lead to simulation mismatch.
# Info: [44842]: Compilation successfully completed.
# Info: [44856]: Total lines of RTL compiled: 17.
# Info: [44835]: Total CPU time for compilation: 0.0 secs.
# Info: [44513]: Overall running time for compilation: 1.0 secs.
# Info: [668]: Current working directory: /home/runner/impl_1.
# Info: [15334]: Doing rtl optimizations.
# Info: [671]: Finished compiling design.
# Info: [668]: Current working directory: /home/runner/impl_1.
# Info: [20026]: MultiProc: Precision will use a maximum of 8 logical processors.
# Info: [15002]: Optimizing design view:.work.R.INTERFACE
# Info: [15002]: Optimizing design view:.work.R.INTERFACE
# Info: [8010]: Gated clock transformations: Begin...
# Info: [8010]: Gated clock transformations: End...
# Info: [8053]: Added global buffer BUFGP for Port port:clk
# Info: [3027]: Writing file: /home/runner/impl_1/R.edf.
# Info: [3027]: Writing file: /home/runner/impl_1/R.xdc.
# Info: -- Writing file /home/runner/impl_1/R.tcl
# Info: [3027]: Writing file: /home/runner/impl_1/R.v.
# Info: -- Writing file /home/runner/impl_1/R.tcl
# Info: [671]: Finished synthesizing design.
# Info: [11019]: Total CPU time for synthesis: 0.8 s secs.
# Info: [11020]: Overall running time for synthesis: 1.0 s secs.
# Info: /home/runner/impl_1/precision_tech.sdc
# Info: [3027]: Writing file: /home/runner/precision.v.
# Info: [3027]: Writing file: /home/runner/precision.xdc.
# Info: -- Writing file /home/runner/impl_1/R.tcl
# Info: Info, Command 'auto_write' finished successfully
# Info: Num  File Type  Path
# Info: --------------------------------------------------------
# Info: 0               /home/runner/impl_1/R_area.rep
# Info: 1               /home/runner/impl_1/R_con_rep.sdc
# Info: 2               /home/runner/impl_1/R_tech_con_rep.sdc
# Info: 3               /home/runner/impl_1/R_fsm.rep
# Info: 4               /home/runner/impl_1/R_dsp_modes.rep
# Info: 5               /home/runner/impl_1/R_ram_modes.rep
# Info: 6               /home/runner/impl_1/R_env.htm
# Info: 7               /home/runner/impl_1/R.edf
# Info: 8               /home/runner/impl_1/R.v
# Info: 9               /home/runner/impl_1/R.xdc
# Info: 10              /home/runner/impl_1/R.tcl
# Info: ***************************************************************
# Info: Device Utilization for 7A100TCSG324
# Info: ***************************************************************
# Info: Resource                          Used    Avail   Utilization
# Info: ---------------------------------------------------------------
# Info: IOs                               19      210       9.05%
# Info: Global Buffers                    1       32        3.12%
# Info: LUTs                              1       63400     0.00%
# Info: CLB Slices                        1       15850     0.01%
# Info: Dffs or Latches                   8       126800    0.01%
# Info: Block RAMs                        0       135       0.00%
# Info: DSP48E1s                          0       240       0.00%
# Info: ---------------------------------------------------------------
# Info: *****************************************************
# Info: Library: work    Cell: R    View: INTERFACE
# Info: *****************************************************
# Info:  Number of ports :                           19
# Info:  Number of nets :                            40
# Info:  Number of instances :                       29
# Info:  Number of references to this view :          0
# Info: Total accumulated area :
# Info:  Number of Dffs or Latches :                  8
# Info:  Number of LUTs :                             1
# Info:  Number of Primitive LUTs :                   1
# Info:  Number of accumulated instances :           29
# Info: *****************************
# Info:  IO Register Mapping Report
# Info: *****************************
# Info: Design: work.R.INTERFACE
# Info: +---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
# Info: | Port                | Direction |   INFF   |  OUTFF   |  TRIFF   |
# Info: +---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
# Info: | data_from_bus(7)    | Input     |          |          |          |
# Info: +---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
# Info: | data_from_bus(6)    | Input     |          |          |          |
# Info: +---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
# Info: | data_from_bus(5)    | Input     |          |          |          |
# Info: +---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
# Info: | data_from_bus(4)    | Input     |          |          |          |
# Info: +---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
# Info: | data_from_bus(3)    | Input     |          |          |          |
# Info: +---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
# Info: | data_from_bus(2)    | Input     |          |          |          |
# Info: +---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
# Info: | data_from_bus(1)    | Input     |          |          |          |
# Info: +---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
# Info: | data_from_bus(0)    | Input     |          |          |          |
# Info: +---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
# Info: | data_to_bus(7)      | Output    |          |          |          |
# Info: +---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
# Info: | data_to_bus(6)      | Output    |          |          |          |
# Info: +---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
# Info: | data_to_bus(5)      | Output    |          |          |          |
# Info: +---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
# Info: | data_to_bus(4)      | Output    |          |          |          |
# Info: +---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
# Info: | data_to_bus(3)      | Output    |          |          |          |
# Info: +---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
# Info: | data_to_bus(2)      | Output    |          |          |          |
# Info: +---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
# Info: | data_to_bus(1)      | Output    |          |          |          |
# Info: +---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
# Info: | data_to_bus(0)      | Output    |          |          |          |
# Info: +---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
# Info: | clk                 | Input     |          |          |          |
# Info: +---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
# Info: | read                | Input     |          |          |          |
# Info: +---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
# Info: | write               | Input     |          |          |          |
# Info: +---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
# Info: Total registers mapped: 0
# Info: [12022]: Design has no timing constraint and no timing information.
# Info: //
# Info: // Verilog description for cell R,
# Info: // Sun May  8 19:57:18 2022
# Info: //
# Info: // Precision RTL Synthesis, 64-bit 2021.1.0.4//
# Info: module R ( data_from_bus, data_to_bus, clk, read, write ) ;
# Info:     input [7:0]data_from_bus ;
# Info:     output [7:0]data_to_bus ;
# Info:     input clk ;
# Info:     input read ;
# Info:     input write ;
# Info:     wire [7:0]data_from_bus_int;
# Info:     wire clk_int;
# Info:     wire read_int, write_int, nx57998z1, nx198;
# Info:     wire [7:0]r_reg;
# Info:     OBUFT \data_to_bus_triBus1(0)  (.O (data_to_bus[0]), .I (r_reg[0]), .T (
# Info:           nx57998z1)) ;
# Info:     OBUFT \data_to_bus_triBus1(1)  (.O (data_to_bus[1]), .I (r_reg[1]), .T (
# Info:           nx57998z1)) ;
# Info:     OBUFT \data_to_bus_triBus1(2)  (.O (data_to_bus[2]), .I (r_reg[2]), .T (
# Info:           nx57998z1)) ;
# Info:     OBUFT \data_to_bus_triBus1(3)  (.O (data_to_bus[3]), .I (r_reg[3]), .T (
# Info:           nx57998z1)) ;
# Info:     OBUFT \data_to_bus_triBus1(4)  (.O (data_to_bus[4]), .I (r_reg[4]), .T (
# Info:           nx57998z1)) ;
# Info:     OBUFT \data_to_bus_triBus1(5)  (.O (data_to_bus[5]), .I (r_reg[5]), .T (
# Info:           nx57998z1)) ;
# Info:     OBUFT \data_to_bus_triBus1(6)  (.O (data_to_bus[6]), .I (r_reg[6]), .T (
# Info:           nx57998z1)) ;
# Info:     OBUFT \data_to_bus_triBus1(7)  (.O (data_to_bus[7]), .I (r_reg[7]), .T (
# Info:           nx57998z1)) ;
# Info:     IBUF write_ibuf (.O (write_int), .I (write)) ;
# Info:     IBUF read_ibuf (.O (read_int), .I (read)) ;
# Info:     IBUF \data_from_bus_ibuf(0)  (.O (data_from_bus_int[0]), .I (
# Info:          data_from_bus[0])) ;
# Info:     IBUF \data_from_bus_ibuf(1)  (.O (data_from_bus_int[1]), .I (
# Info:          data_from_bus[1])) ;
# Info:     IBUF \data_from_bus_ibuf(2)  (.O (data_from_bus_int[2]), .I (
# Info:          data_from_bus[2])) ;
# Info:     IBUF \data_from_bus_ibuf(3)  (.O (data_from_bus_int[3]), .I (
# Info:          data_from_bus[3])) ;
# Info:     IBUF \data_from_bus_ibuf(4)  (.O (data_from_bus_int[4]), .I (
# Info:          data_from_bus[4])) ;
# Info:     IBUF \data_from_bus_ibuf(5)  (.O (data_from_bus_int[5]), .I (
# Info:          data_from_bus[5])) ;
# Info:     IBUF \data_from_bus_ibuf(6)  (.O (data_from_bus_int[6]), .I (
# Info:          data_from_bus[6])) ;
# Info:     IBUF \data_from_bus_ibuf(7)  (.O (data_from_bus_int[7]), .I (
# Info:          data_from_bus[7])) ;
# Info:     INV ix57998z1315 (.O (nx57998z1), .I (write_int)) ;
# Info:     BUFGP clk_ibuf (.O (clk_int), .I (clk)) ;
# Info:     GND ps_gnd (.G (nx198)) ;
# Info:     FDRE \reg_r_reg(7)  (.Q (r_reg[7]), .C (clk_int), .CE (read_int), .D (
# Info:          data_from_bus_int[7]), .R (nx198)) ;
# Info:     FDRE \reg_r_reg(6)  (.Q (r_reg[6]), .C (clk_int), .CE (read_int), .D (
# Info:          data_from_bus_int[6]), .R (nx198)) ;
# Info:     FDRE \reg_r_reg(5)  (.Q (r_reg[5]), .C (clk_int), .CE (read_int), .D (
# Info:          data_from_bus_int[5]), .R (nx198)) ;
# Info:     FDRE \reg_r_reg(4)  (.Q (r_reg[4]), .C (clk_int), .CE (read_int), .D (
# Info:          data_from_bus_int[4]), .R (nx198)) ;
# Info:     FDRE \reg_r_reg(3)  (.Q (r_reg[3]), .C (clk_int), .CE (read_int), .D (
# Info:          data_from_bus_int[3]), .R (nx198)) ;
# Info:     FDRE \reg_r_reg(2)  (.Q (r_reg[2]), .C (clk_int), .CE (read_int), .D (
# Info:          data_from_bus_int[2]), .R (nx198)) ;
# Info:     FDRE \reg_r_reg(1)  (.Q (r_reg[1]), .C (clk_int), .CE (read_int), .D (
# Info:          data_from_bus_int[1]), .R (nx198)) ;
# Info:     FDRE \reg_r_reg(0)  (.Q (r_reg[0]), .C (clk_int), .CE (read_int), .D (
# Info:          data_from_bus_int[0]), .R (nx198)) ;
# Info: endmodule
```